# How the recursion would be?

Tags: c++11

I have a function with "for" loop and I want to implement the recursion to replace the for loop. However I cannot use the global variables ie 'counter' ,so now I am logically confused how can I implement the recursion.

```
int makeHorizontalLine(char canvas[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL], int row, int col, int length){
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<length ; i++){
    if ((i+col) >= MAX_COL)
        return counter;
    canvas[row][i+col] = '-';
    counter += 1;
}
```

This is what I tried in the recursion.

```
int makeHorizontalLine(char canvas[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL], int row, int col, int length){
    if (col >= MAX_COL)
        return length;
    if (length != 0){
        if (col < MAX_COL){
            makeHorizontalLine(canvas, row, col+1, length-1);
            return length;
        }


    }
```

As I cannot use the global variable so I tried to assign recursion such as

```
makeHorizontalLine(canvas, row, col+1; length -1)
```

and when length = 0 to stop the recursion, but I cannot return what I want in the recursion if

```
if ((i+col) >= MAX_COL)
```

So I got logically stucked in the recursion. Please give me some advice. Appreciate.

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion in this code? It's not appropriate here.

Comment: It's unclear what this function is supposed to return and please note that the first snippet lacks a return statement (and the final bracket) at least.

Comment: Please state whether this is a homework assignment or the reason for changing to recursion.